# MVC4 JsonResult from jQuery Ajax call not found

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

My Ajax call looks like this:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/GetStuff",
            success: function (data) {
                getStuff_callback(data);
            },
            dataType: "json",
            traditional: true
        });
```

Everything works fine on local but when I publish the project to a folder called "ws" on my FTP server, the GetStuff JsonResult function cannot be found unless I do like this **"url: "/ws/Home/GetStuff""**... which is something I really don't wanna have to do everytime I want to publish.

I tried **@Url.Action("GetStuff", "Home")** but I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid flags supplied to RegExp constructor 'GetStuff'" in Chrome debugger.

Comment: `@Url.Action("GetStuff", "Home")` prints literal text. You need to wrap it in `""` to create a Javascript string literal.

Comment: +1 Sure as heck helped me...

Comment: +1 helped me, sure as heck